# how to include plugin files in another javascript file

Tags: jquery, html, plugins, jquery-plugins

I send a part of my code to my HTML page using html(...) with jquery. I have used a jquery plugin (Tooltipsetrt http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/?) on the part i have sent with html(...). 
but my plugin doesn't work on that section. 
I think i must include Tooltipster's plugin files on my jquery. is it right? if yes, how should i do it?

this is the section which i send with html in my jquery file:

```
$('.donate_test').html('<a class="question-mark tooltip"  href="google.com" title="This is my link's tooltip message!">(?)</a>');
```

Comment: It could be that you just have an error in your code.  You need to escape that single quote in your title attribute.  `title="This is my link\'s tooltip message!"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinitialise your Tooltip plugin after you have added that  tag.

```
$('.donate_test').html('<a class="question-mark tooltip"  href="google.com" title="This is my link's tooltip message!">(?)</a>');
$('.tooltip').tooltipster();
```

Your initial call to tooltipster() is probably in your $(document).ready(), so if you add a new element that needs to have a tooltip, you're going to have to call the plugin again.